# Android tab page indicator place bottom of viewpager with line lindicator on top

Tags: android, android-tabs, viewpagerindicator

I am using TabePageIndicator and by default the tabs are top aligned. But in my App I need to place them at the bottom of the view pager. I tried with the following code, tabs are bottom aligned but the line still shows at the bottom. Please provide me with any possible solutions. Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="14dp" />

    <com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:linePosition="top" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative margin to achieve the effect, but be aware that for LinearLayout, the below element will layer on top of the previous element.